# How to show a inserted record in my kendoUI grid without refreshing the page by using iframe

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery

i have a kendoui grid in my Grid.aspx page that shows my data from sqlserver, and then i add a button by id:framebtn
in Grid.aspx page,when i click on framebtn another page (WebForm1.aspx) will popup by using ifram.
 in my WebForm1.aspx i have a textbox(by id="txtName") and one button(btnRegist) and when you click on btnRegist in WebForm1.aspx it insert every thing in the txtName to my sqlserver and then you can see it on  kendoui grid in Grid.aspx if you refreshing the Grid.aspx page after inserting... i want to a way to rebind my kendoui grid after inserting a record in iframe automatically without refreshing the page????? any body can help me please?

this is my added explanation:

i bind my grid by using json like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                    var crudServiceBaseUrl = "http://demos.kendoui.com/service",
                        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                            transport: {
                                read: function (p) {

                                    $.ajax({
                                        type: "POST",
                                        url: "./Grid.aspx/GetCities",
                                        data: '{}',
                                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        success: function (response) {
                                            p.success(response.d);

                                        },
                                        failure: function (response) {
                                            alert(response.d);
                                        },
                                        error: function (response) {
                                            alert(response.d);
                                        }
                                    });
```

GetCities is a webmethod function in my Grid.aspx.cs that get list of cities then show in my grid kenoui in Grid.aspx page... i added a buuton (framebtn) that popup my WebForm1.aspx(WebForm1.aspx have a textbox by id="txtName" and a button by id="btnRegist") when you write in the txtName and then press btnRegist it added a record in my sqlserver database and my kendoui Grid too , if i want to see it i should refreshing the page(i mean Grid.aspx) ,, but i want when i press on the btnRegist immediately show inserted record in my grid without refreshing the Grid.aspx

Comment: It's good if you post some code here.

Comment: i added some more explanation with some code if it is possible please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this js function to `Grid.aspx` page:

```
function RefreshGrid(){
    var grid = $('#YourGridId').data("kendoGrid");
    grid.dataSource.read();
    grid.refresh();
}
```

of course replace `YourGridId` with actual id of the grid element.
in `btnRegist_Click` method from `WebForm1.aspx` write:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "refresh", "parent.RefreshGrid();", true);
```

Comment: my friend i dont know how mark your answer .. do you mean i vote up your answer?

Comment: Click on `Tick` mark below vote buttons next to my answer. And vote up if u can.